# What is the origin of "GO + VERB + ING"?

Tags: etymology, grammaticality, verbs, ing

The construction GO + V + ING is among one of the first things a learner is taught. Take for instance the verb **swim**, very often English expresses the activity in the present simple like this:

> I go swimming twice a week

This construction is used with any ‘outdoorsy’ or sport activity that employs a verb, such as:

> He goes skiing whenever he can
>   She goes dancing with her friends.
>   We go walking every day
>   They go surfing at/on weekends.

The verb GO is inflected to express different tenses such as

> He didn't go swimming.
>   She's going fishing  in the morning.
>   We went bowling last night.
>   He'd gone hunting before.
>   They've just gone rock climbing.

***Shopping*** and ***drinking*** seem to break the mould, they are neither sports nor games, but you can think of them as being “outdoor” or pastime activities. You can go drinking with your mates, and while many Italians believe [*lo shopping*](http://d.repubblica.it/attualita/2013/07/20/news/shopping_uomini-1727615/) is only the activity that young girls do in boutiques; people also **go shopping** for *food* etc. And nowadays, we *go shopping online*.

> They've gone shopping.
>   Let's go drinking.

But GO + V + ING for the following activities is “ungrammatical” or dubious at best:

> 1. *I go playing tennis regularly. (maybe this one's OKish)
> 2. *You go working twice a week.
> 3. ?Let's go criketing/baseballing/basketballing (etc.)
> 4. *He goes cleaning his car  at/on the weekend.
> 5. ?She goes painting outdoors every Sunday.
> 6. *You go washing up after dinner.
> 7. *Let's go eating out.
> 8. *Let's go seeing a movie.

---

**Questions**

- What is the origin of GO + V + ING? When was this construction first noted?
- Is this construction becoming increasingly flexible in English speaking countries?
- Are the expressions *go shopping* and *go drinking* considered isolated/unique cases? I am particularly interested in hearing about activities that are unrelated to sports/games/outdoors but use GO + V + ING.
  For example, @pazzo's suggestions: [*gamble* and *window shop*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253849/what-is-the-origin-of-go-verb-ing#comment554547_253849).

Comment: 'Now, don't you **go** **climbing** trees in those clothes: you **go** **and** change.' I hear.

Comment: @Hugh  I did mention "go rock climbing" :)

Comment: @Mari-Lou_A, Sure,  I was just adding a negative inflected form.

Comment: I see this usage to be for *leisure time activities* that one leaves the house to do: gambling, caroling, sightseeing, people watching, trick-or-treating, model airplane flying, cow tipping, horseback riding. That some leisure activities can also be competitive sports does not alter this. Someone competing in Olympic skiing is not 'going skiing'. Rough guide: you play sports and you do yoga, karate, etc. *Play golf* (golfing) seems an exception. All the -ing ones are also verbs: I golf, I drink, I gamble, I window shop, I bird watch, I horseback ride, I rock climb, (non -ing forms).

Comment: _Go cricketing/baseballing_ seems perfectly fine to me. So does _go tennising_, except for the fact that _tennis_ isn't normally used as a verb.

Comment: Could we go visiting?

Comment: @pazzo Yes, I should have used the term *leisure activities*, a more descriptive term than "outdoorsy".  I had to look up [*cow tipping*](http://modernfarmer.com/2013/09/cow-tipping-myth-or-bullcrap/), it seems a bit of an urban myth. I doubt you would want to tip more than one cow on any excursion :). The "gamblling" and "bird watching" are good suggestions, but the latter is still an outdoor activity. "I go people watching", do people say that?

Comment: Funny, you can say it exactly the same way in Russian.

Comment: @MishaRosnach What? "Cow tipping"  or  "I go people watching"?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet  "I go tennising", I don't know about that. Do young people say: "I tennis twice a week"? What about **“Shall we/Let's go lunching”**? It doesn't sound terrible, but if a non-native speaker were to say this, would he or she be understood? Or would an American think they were speaking incorrectly?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I admit I've never heard _tennis_ used as a verb; but I don't think I'd bat too much of an eyelid (if eyelids may be so quantified) if someone used it humorously. You can just go walking, though, or go carolling (at Christmas). Leisurely activities is part of it, but there is more…

Comment: @Mari-Lou: "I go people watching." The go-verb-ing combination. Well, Russian doesn't have ing verbs, so it's more like infinitive.

Comment: 'I go baseballing' and 'I go tennising' are not idiomatic in English. There are zero Google book search results for either phrase, as well as none for 'go cricketing'. Yes, people watching is a leisure activity. I don't find 'let's go lunching' idiomatic. 'let's go eat lunch'

Comment: *Let's do lunch* is idiomatic. I'm not saying people can't start saying *let's go lunching*, but I'm unaware of anyone who does.

Comment: @pazzo - you mean, "let's go luncheon."

Comment: @LittleEva: "Luncheon, brother!  Luncheon."

Comment: Is it possible to take any activity and turn it into an "ing" form?  I don't think so.  Doesn't the base word also have to function as a verb?  Baseball is not a verb, so although we can say the sentence "I go baseballing twice a week," our brain will say "nope."  But if I give you a word such as "shayzu" and say "I go shayzuing twice a week," you'll say "ok."  BTW "shayzu" is shoe in Chinese.  "I go shoeing twice a week," doesn't work in English.  I think your brain steps in to say what is possible...I know that sounds obvious but in this case I think it's worth exploring.

Comment: I'd say it's not all that productive a device. Collins Cobuild labels it a phase structure (along with other two-part activities such as 'stand watching', 'sit knitting', 'come shopping', 'risk trying' ...). 'Go bird-watching / carol-singing / collecting (intransitive, or 'We went collecting blackberries' say)' are non-sporty examples.

Comment: I have just become aware of a number of linguistics papers that deal with this construction, and in particular with the question of why we can *go drinking* but can't normally * *go eating*. See my answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463830/why-dont-we-say-were-going-eating/463852#463852).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The origin goes back to Old English, as far as the year 1000 or earlier (according to *OED*). *OED* gives OE (Old English) for the date section of the two earliest citations.

Definition:

> With participle indicating a concomitant action or activity.

Earliest citation:

> *Þa eodon hi sprecende ymbe þæs hælendes þrowunge him betwynan.*
>
> <sub>Ælfric of Eynsham, *Catholic Homilies*</sub>

Other examples in chronological order are: (*OED*)

- eodon biddende, OE
- eode singuynde, c1300
- go wryȝinge, c1380
- go hippinge, c1430
- go walkyng, 1483
- went preachyng, a1535
- wente askyng & serchyng, 1548
- go begging, 1615
- went looking about, 1658
- Went prancing, 1719
- went mumping, 1775
- went dancing, 1841
- went sailing, 1895
- went rushing down, 1930
- went sprawling, 1988
- went sniffing, 2013

*OED* mentions that the above definition is the formally similar sense of the following definition:

> *intr.* To move, travel, or proceed (to somewhere) so as to perform a specified action, or for the purpose of a specified or implied activity.
>
> **f.** With verbal noun or gerund.
>
> (b) Without prefixed particle.

The earliest citation is from a1500:

> Euery-on an hauke on honde ber, & **went haukyng** [c1330 *Auch.* riden on haukin] by þe ryuer.
>
> *Sir Orfeo*, Harley

Other examples in chronological order are: (*OED*)

- went hunting, 1658
- have gone hunting and hawking, 1672
- go Hunting or Hawking, 1707
- go shooting of Birds, 1749
- goes gunning , 1846
- went gambling, 1861
- ‘go clamming’, 1887
- went automobiling, 1915
- went fishing, 1933
- going camping, 1960
- go clubbing, 2003

*OED* also gives:

> (a) With prefixed *a* (also *†on*) Now *arch.* and *regional.*

The earliest citation is from c1300:

> Þis child scholde **wende An hontingue**.
>
> <sub>*St. Kenelm* (Laud) 148 in C. Horstmann *Early S.-Eng. Legendary*</sub>

**Conclusion:**

It looks like this construction was first being used for actions, and then extended to activities. In *OED*, the earliest example with an outdoor activity is "go walking" (if we exclude the constructions with prefixed *a*). Then, we start seeing examples like "go hunting" starting from 1500s as sport-like activities. Although, the earlier form is with prefixed *a*. (*go a hunting*).

We are more familiar with this construction for sports and outdoor activities but it can be used with other leisure and indoor activities like bowling, shopping, dancing, clubbing etc.

Comment: What sports? It does not work for sports. Perhaps only golf, which is also a leisure activity.

Comment: @pazzo: http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/go_gerund.htm

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253849/what-is-the-origin-of-go-verb-ing/253921?noredirect=1#comment554547_253849

Comment: Could you give the modern English for the first four examples you cited, please?

Comment: *Went sprawling*, though it looks as if it fits in the list, really doesn't: falling over does not imply intention, rather the reverse.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I know that they are "go + verb + ing" form but I'm not 100% sure about their modern equivalents. I think *biddende* is begging and *sprecende* is speaking. *singuynde* might be singing. *wryȝinge* might be writing (or wrying?).

Answer (score 5):

“To go hunting” derives from an older form such as *to go a-hunting*. Wiktionary has an article on this a-gerund under the headline [**a- -ing**](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/a-_-ing).

Wiktionary says this prefix **a-** was the form *on*. I'm not so sure. Theoretically this prefix might derive from various prepositions *at*, *to*, *on*, *in*.
Originally the word formation was ***a-*** + **gerund** with the unambiguous ending *-ing(e)*, Old English -ung/-ing. Later on, when the original ending of the present participle changed from *ende* over *inde* to *inge* both endings developed the same form and today, at least in most textbooks, these forms are seen as participles, though gerund would make more sense, as such forms are parallel to German

- *Wir gingen zum Jagen*—literally:  "We went to the hunting".

Later this prefix was no longer used except in some dialects and in poetry where an archaic effect is sought.

Comment: _Go a-surfing_ sounds Pythonesque.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth because they wanted to make it sound old.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/on#etymonline_v_7013 one of the older meanings of *on* was "in" or "into", denoting direction rather than just position, and it's fairly common in compounds, such as *ahead* (toward the front, forward) or *aloof* (toward the wind's direction).

Answer (score 2):

***First noted?***
*Gone fishing* and *Gone fishin'* are in use as far back as the NGram goes.

...and here's the *King James Bible* (1611) for John 21:3

> Simon Peter saith vnto them, I goe a fishing. They say vnto him, Wee
>   also goe with thee. They went foorth and entred into a ship
>   immediatly, and that night they caught nothing.

translating **‘Υπάγω ‘αλιέυειν**  vb + infinitive vb  'I-go to-fish.