# Why don't we say "We're going eating"?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

I found an interesting observation about the English language in [this answer post](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/1015):

> Try explaining to a Finn sometime [...] why *We're going shopping* is OK in English, while **We're going eating* isn't[.]

I'm an American native speaker, and although I *agree* that "We're going eating" isn't acceptable, I have no idea why!

(The correct sentence is "We're going out to eat.")

So why is "We're going eating" unacceptable, while many similar sentences (we're going shopping, we're going skiing) are?

Are there any patterns in the language that would allow an English student to predict that "We're going eating" is not an acceptable sentence, without already knowing beforehand?

Comment: This isn't good enough for an answer, but I wonder if it only works for activities that commonly end in *-ing*. Most people wouldn't say "we're eating tonight" when they mean "we're going out to eat" (even though it's grammatically correct). *Shopping* and *skiing*, on the other hand, work in that case.

Comment: I find it quite natural to say *They'll be going [out] **drinking** tonight*. I think that's only valid because we know it refers to a "special kind" of drinking (that gets you drunk). I can't see exactly why the same doesn't apply to going out for a "special" kind of eating in a swanky restaurant, but unquestionably it doesn't (except perhaps as a facetious usage). It's an intriguing question, to me at least.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Would you say that going (out) drinking generally involves a pub crawl of some sort, or at least moving around within a drinking establishment, or can it mean just bellying up to the bar and sitting there all night getting drunk? My general instinct is that "going verbing" generally includes a literal movement element, so "going driving" or "going swimming" but not "going studying" or "going gaming". But I don't do the "special kind" of drinking so I'm not sure whether that fits. (And on the other hand, "going playing" sounds wrong to me, so maybe that's the wrong track.)

Comment: related: [What is the origin of “GO + VERB + ING”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253849/what-is-the-origin-of-go-verb-ing)

Comment: @1006a: Apart from the fact that *to go [out] verbing* obviously involves at least "moving" from current location to wherever "verbing" takes place, I don't see any particular connotations of moving around directly related to the specific activity. You could go [out] *gambling* every Friday night, for example - which might mean spending the entire evening sitting at a card table.

Comment: Ah, you're right about gambling @FumbleFingers. I'm still curious about "going drinking", though.

Comment: @1006a: You might think that going [out] drinking implies moving from place to place (a pub crawl), but so far as I'm concerned it could equally well apply to someone who spends his entire Friday night sitting in the corner of a bar. I certainly can't see any reason to suppose there's a *general* implication of "movement" in the construction ***to go [out] verbing***.

Comment: Just a note that I have found a number of academic papers that deal with exactly this question. I have updated my answer so that it now includes the conclusions of the latest one of them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. I was pretty tentative in that impression of "go verbing" anyway, and I think the quintessential "gone fishing" mentioned below, which I always imagine as someone asleep on a riverbank with a hat pulled over the eyes and a rod stuck in the ground, pretty much puts the nail in its coffin. (Though there's still something about "going sitting" or "going sleeping" that sounds even more wrong to me than "going eating".)

Comment: I read exactly the same post, and had the same question, and wanted to ask in this SE, and Google brought me here. I am not native but consider myself to be a capable English speaker, and I do not find `go eating` to be weird. This makes me sad. Why do I not share the intuition? Am I the only one here who thinks the division is nonexistent? Can it be that `go eating` is weird only in the same sense that `colorless green sleeps furiously` is strange, and the "grammar" suggested is merely a psychological reality? Feel like we are brought back to all the old debates on Chomsky and I-language.

Comment: Because it is not English **usage**.

Comment: @David That's just a rephrasing of the question with the word "because" substituted for "why."

Comment: No. What I’m saying is that this is a site concerned with two aspects of the English language — logical structural aspects that conform to rules— grammar, and irregular aspects that cannot be put into a grammatical framework — usage. If you ask “why” about the latter you are embarking into psychology, which is neither an objective  science nor the concern of this site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is probably no strict pattern, but one can nevertheless identify a tendency, namely, that the gerund-participal should be an intransitive verb denoting a leisure activity, preferably a physical one that counts as an 'experience'.

EDIT: Since first posting this answer, I have become aware of several linguistics papers that deal exactly with this issue. The latest one is Salkie (2010) (see the reference list at the end; Salkie's paper is free to download). He calls this construction 'expeditionary *go*', and discussess it together with other two: *go for a* N and  *have a* N. His question is exactly how come we can *go drinking / go for a drink / have a drink*, but can't *<sup>?</sup>go eating / *go for an eat / *have an eat*. He also distingishes these constructions from several others that have the same superficial form but are in fact different. His answer to his main question is more or less along the lines suggested in the original version of this post. I will reproduce a relevant section from this paper below.

Here is the rest of my original post.

**Comprehensive grammars**

[CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468) and [ComGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0582517346) do not address this question. The best I can do as far as such sources is this: what we have here is a construction where *go* functions as a [catenative verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenative_verb), which takes a gerund-participial as a complement. In general, complementation implies **licensing**, meaning that the entity which accepts the complement (here the verb *go*) will not accept just any word as a complement, even if the word is of the proper grammatical format (here the gerund-participial form of an intransitive verb). Unfortunately, usually there are no absolute rules as far as which words are licensed to appear as complements. There can be tendencies, but, in the end, such properties should be recorded in dictionaries. Or at least that's what linguists tell us.

**Dictionaries**

In practice, dictionaries are never as comprehensive as that. In the present case, even the most comprehensive dictionary of all, the *OED*, records this kind of usage of *go* as follows:

> 30. *intransitive.* To move, travel, or proceed (to somewhere) so as to perform a specified action, or for the purpose of a specified or implied activity.
>
> f. With verbal noun or gerund.
>
> (b) Without prefixed particle.

This is followed by several examples, based on which we conclude that the following gerunds, at least, are allowed: ***hunting, hawking, shooting, gunning, gambling, clamming, automobiling, fishing, camping,*** and ***clubbing***. But in fact it's worse than that, because all but the last two examples are from before 1960 (in fact from 1933 and earlier), and so all the previous ones may well be obsolete or at least dated. Moreover, this is clearly not the complete list, since at least *swimming* is missing. This would not be so bad if the *OED's* entry for *swim* recorded that it can appear in such a construction, but it does not. And **even this** would **still** be OK if this meant that, by default, intransitive verbs can enter this construction, with some exceptions which have a note to that effect in their entry. But there is no such note in the *OED's* entry for *eat*.

**An attempt at discerning a tendency**

The most promising lead that I found so far (EDIT: I have since found several academic papers, see above) says the following ([here](https://englishwithkim.com/go-ing-gerund-fun-activities/)):

> In English, we use the grammar structure **go+ing** to talk about leisure activities, or activities we do in our free time. ... It is important to mention that **go+ing** is used to indicate the **whole activity**. When I talk about **going swimming,** I am describing the **entire experience**—wearing a swimsuit, putting on sunscreen, going to the pool or beach, swimming laps or enjoying the waves, getting wet, drying off afterwards. **Go+ing** gives us a **mental image** of the **complete activity**. If I just wanted to talk about the action of swimming, I would simply use the verb “to swim.” For example, “I **swam** ten laps in the pool today.” In this case, I am **only** describing the **action** of swimming, **not the experience**.

Let's test that. Note that although we can't say

**we are going eating*,

we **can** say

*we are going [drinking](https://books.google.com/books?id=mBZntknoLCkC&lpg=PA39&dq=%22going%20drinking%22&pg=PA39#v=onepage&q=%22going%20drinking%22&f=false)/[dining](https://books.google.com/books?id=M_hkCQAAQBAJ&lpg=PT92&dq=%22going%20dining%22&pg=PT92#v=onepage&q=%22going%20dining%22&f=false).*

Arguably, we can even say such things as

*we are going [lobster](https://www.facebook.com/UNIVISION23MIAMI/posts/its-that-time-of-year-again-lobster-mini-season-whos-going-lobster-hunting-bette/10152566242807356/)/[chocolate](http://chalkolatte.blogspot.com/search?q=wine+tasting) eating.*

Some other things one can *'go doing'*: *[wine tasting](https://books.google.com/books?id=hzmQCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT112&dq=%22going%20wine%20tasting%22&pg=PT112#v=onepage&q=%22going%20wine%20tasting%22&f=false), [running](https://books.google.com/books?id=hReCAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PT65&dq=%22going%20running%22&pg=PT65#v=onepage&q=%22going%20running%22&f=false), [walking](https://books.google.com/books?id=DcK6dfsgNT8C&lpg=PA99&dq=%22going%20walking%22&pg=PA99#v=onepage&q=%22going%20walking%22&f=false), [swimming](https://books.google.com/books?id=94RRBQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA50&dq=%22going%20swimming%22&pg=PA50#v=onepage&q=%22going%20swimming%22&f=false), [hunting](https://books.google.com/books?id=aNw4F0LFIHQC&lpg=PA143&dq=%22going%20hunting%22&pg=PA143#v=onepage&q=%22going%20hunting%22&f=false), [sightseeing](https://books.google.com/books?id=GMbUgRN2XYUC&lpg=PT245&dq=%22going%20sightseeing%22&pg=PT245#v=onepage&q=%22going%20sightseeing%22&f=false), [climbing](https://books.google.com/books?id=2COWAgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA96&dq=%22going%20climbing%22&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q=%22going%20climbing%22&f=false), [camping](https://books.google.com/books?id=pJUFOhyKWpgC&lpg=PA20&dq=%22are%20going%20camping%22&pg=PA20#v=onepage&q=%22are%20going%20camping%22&f=false), [flying](https://books.google.com/books?id=wlOUvW7XtlYC&lpg=PA98&dq=%22are%20going%20flying%22&pg=PA98#v=onepage&q=%22are%20going%20flying%22&f=false), [bar hopping](https://books.google.com/books?id=ouTaAnG0ipwC&lpg=PA228&dq=%22are%20going%20bar%20hopping%22&pg=PA228#v=onepage&q=%22are%20going%20bar%20hopping%22&f=false), [shopping](https://books.google.com/books?id=pWLLK2XKY1EC&lpg=PT205&dq=%22going%20shopping%22&pg=PT205#v=onepage&q=%22going%20shopping%22&f=false), [painting](https://books.google.com/books?id=otl4JFLiA_UC&lpg=PA2&dq=%22going%20painting%22&pg=PA2#v=onepage&q=%22going%20painting%22&f=false), [decorating](https://books.google.com/books?id=__UKmSApfy8C&lpg=PT122&dq=%22going%20decorating%22&pg=PT122#v=onepage&q=%22going%20decorating%22&f=false), [drawing](https://books.google.com/books?id=cIfsAAAAMAAJ&q=%22going+drawing%22&dq=%22going+drawing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvuY6UlbHdAhWHt1MKHYf7BdgQ6AEIwgEwHQ), [prospecting](https://books.google.com/books?id=zmopM8QYA_sC&lpg=PA103&dq=%22going%20prospecting%22&pg=PA103#v=onepage&q=%22going%20prospecting%22&f=false), [cleaning](https://books.google.com/books?id=lETSAAAAIAAJ&q=%22going+cleaning%22&dq=%22going+cleaning%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik89fBl7HdAhVSslMKHQOHDvAQ6AEIYjAM) (also [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=6SLpAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA356&dq=%22going%20cleaning%22&pg=PA356#v=onepage&q=%22going%20cleaning%22&f=false)),...*

Perhaps a more useful question is what expressions are like *eating* in that they cannot be used in such constructions. Proving the negative is of course hard, but here are some plausible candidates: ***sleeping, writing, standing, exercising, learning, playing, playing with friends, cooking, studying, healing, ...***

It seems that the tendency noted in the website holds up pretty well, although not perfectly. In the specific case of *eating*, it is presumably too generic to count as an 'experience', whereas more specific kinds of eating, like *lobster eating* or *dining*, do qualify.

On the other hand, it's not clear why *playing* wouldn't qualify as a leisure activity, and similarly for *exercising* and the related *working out* and *lifting*. However, as I said, tendencies are best we can hope for, so there are bound to be words that don't quite fit the pattern.

**The relevant section from the paper by Salkie (2010)**

> The key to our problem, I shall argue, is two observations about our
> three constructions (*go drinking / go for a drink / have a drink*).　The first
> is that *drink* here normally and most saliently means “drink alcohol.”　A
> key difference between drinking alcohol and eating in societies where
> English is spoken is that effectively transferring food into our body is essential for survival, whereas effectively ingesting alcohol is not: the point
> of “going drinking” is not to satisfy our body’s need for liquid, but to
> have a good time (and possibly satisfy an addiction).　Obviously eating
> food also has important social rituals and behaviours attached to it, but
> they are ancillary to its primary purpose of meeting the human body’s
> need for nutrients.
>
> Secondly, all three constructions are normally intransitive.
> Older readers may remember Hopper and Thompson (1980) which proposed that the key feature of transitivity is not whether or not a verb takes a direct object, but something more fundamental: “the degree of effectiveness or intensity with which the action is transferred from one participant to another” (Hopper and Thompson (1980: 252)).　The purpose of all our three constructions, I claim, is to take an action which normally has high transitivity and move the focus away from the effectiveness of the action and onto the experience of the subject: that is, these constructions make an action intransitive.　Drinking (alcohol) typically focusses on the experience of the subject, as we just noted, so it is compatible with all three constructions.　It seems that with eating food, the effectiveness of the action is crucial enough to make defocussing it impossible or marginal: that is why you can’t normally *<sup>?</sup>go eating / *go for an eat / *have an eat*.
>
> The attempts in the literature to characterise the semantics of these constructions can be seen as steps towards the analysis here.　Bolinger writes about the relationship between an action and its performer.　Dixon alludes to “the subject’s whim” rather than “any transcendental goal.”　Guillemin-Flescher says that the properties of a situation and its occurrence need to be in balance, and Stein refers to “the experience of an activity.”　The fundamental distinction, it would appear, is between the experience of the subject of an action and the effectiveness of the action.　As for Wierzbicka, it is reasonable to argue that ingesting an individual object is more “effective,” to use Hopper and Thompson’s term, than ingesting a mass substance, so eating is more transitive than drinking.　In my analysis, this is relevant but not the fundamental distinction.
>
> A possible weakness of my account is that Hopper and Thompson (1980: 280-290) argue at length that low transitivity correlates with backgrounding in discourse, and high transitivity with foregrounding.　This is not what we find with the predominantly intransitive expeditionary *go*: it would be odd to claim, for instance, that in the song “Gone fishin’,” this activity is backgrounded. However, Hopper and Thompson (1980: 280) assume without argument that “[every] linguistic universal originates in a general pragmatic function.”　Not only is this assumption too strong, but in this case it is not necessary: the distinction between the effectiveness of an action and the experience of the person performing it is straightforward semantics, based on elementary human experiences.　There is no need to assume a pragmatic source for the distinction—though the fact that expeditionary *go* has different discourse properties from the other phenomena that Hopper and Thompson discuss would be worth investigating.

**References**

Berman, A. (1973). "Tripl-*ing*." Linguistic Inquiry **4,** 401-403.

Bolinger, D. (1979). "The Jingle Theory of Double -*ing*." In *Function and
Context in Linguistic Analysis: A Festschrift for William Haas,* D.
Allerton, E. Carney, and D. Holdcroft, eds., pp. 41-56 (Cambridge University
Press,　Cambridge).

Bolinger, D. (1983). "The *Go*-Progressive and Auxiliary Formation." In *Essays
in Honor of Charles F. Hockett,* B. Agard, G. Kelley,
A. Makkai, and V. B. Makkai, eds., pp. 153-167 (E. J. Brill, Leiden).

Dixon, R. M. W. (2005). *A Semantic Approach to English Grammar,* 2nd ed.,
Oxford University Press, Oxford.

Guillemin-Flescher, J. (1999). “Verbes atéliques et construction
d’occurrences.” *Les Opérations de Détermination: Quantification /
Qualification,* A. Deschamps and J. Guillemin-Flescher, eds.,
251-268 (Ophrys, Paris).

Hopper, J. and S. A. Thompson (1980). “Transitivity in Grammar and
Discourse.” Language 56.2, 251-299.

Salkie, R.  (2010). "On *Going*." In B. Capelle and N. Wada, eds., *Distinctions in English grammar: offered to Renaat Declerck*, pp. 169-190 (Kaitakusha, Tokyo); that whole book is downloadable for free [here](https://expertise.hogent.be/files/6011377/01_When_a_Linguist_Draws_a_Line_16_The_Echo_Question_Reported_Speech_.pdf).

Silva, C. M. (1975). "Adverbial -*ing*." Linguistic Inquiry **6,** 346-350.

Wierzbicka, A. (1982). “Why Can You *have a drink* When You Can’t **have an
eat*?” Language 58.4, 753-799.

Comment: Excellent answer! Though I haven’t read Salkie’s paper (and thus don’t know exactly how he treats it), I don’t think this ‘expeditionary _go_’ and the ‘go for a _N_’/‘have a _N_’ expressions should be too closely connected. After all, we can definitely go shopping, but we can’t _*go for a shop_ or _*have a shop_ (unless we’re talking about owning an actual store, which is of course quite unrelated).

Comment: janus-bahs-jacquet A very good point!

Answer (score 5):

> English has constructions like these with *go*:
>
> - *go*+V-*ing* - **Let's go helping/eating* ~ *They went swimming/fishing*
> - *go and*+V - *Let's go and help/eat/swim/fish* ~ *They went and helped/ate/swam/fished*
> - *go*+V - *Let's go help/eat/swim/fish* ~ **They went helped/ate/swam/fished*

as well as

- *come*+V-*ing* - **Let's come helping/eating* ~ *They came swimming/fishing*
- *come and*+V  - *Let's come and help/eat/swim/fish* ~ *They came and helped/ate/swam/fished*
- *come*+V - *Let's come help/eat/swim/fish* ~**They came helped/ate/swam/fished*

with *come*. Note that both sets follow the same patterns:

1. *go/come*+V can be used only as an infinitive: *Let's go help; She volunteered to come cook*, **or**
   in the present tense, but not third person singular: *You come help*, but **She comes help(s)*.
2. *go/come and*+V can be used in any verb form with any verb, provided the verb inflections match, for the purposes of [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/51955/15299):  *Let's go and ask, She went and asked, I have gone and asked*.
3. *go/come*+V-*ing* can be used with the *-ing* verb form of an appropriate verb. Appropriate verb phrases convey a specialized activity that can be performed only in particular places, or only while in motion (whence the *go* and *come*). These include

   - sports like *shooting, hunting, fishing, running, boxing*
   - outdoor activities like *climbing, running, hiking, diving, exploring*, and *spelunking*.

Answer (score 1):

I thunk the  following post from [wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/go-out-to-eat-vs-go-out-eating.2997380/) helps:

> But what about: "We go out eating"? -> Eating is the present participle and modifies "go out". The -ing form indicates a duration. Therefore, as has been said "***We exit whilst we are in the process of eating [something.]"***
>
> "Eating" as a gerund (in the sense of a noun) is not common in the context you give and therefore it sounds strange, except in the sense of exiting whilst eating (i.e. in a sense that is more adverbial).
>
> ***The example with drinking differs "we go out drinking"*** = "We go out to indulge ourselves in the action of drinking alcohol." or (less likely) "We exit whilst we are in the process of drinking [something.]" (i.e. in a sense that is more adverbial).
>
> Drinking is used commonly as a noun and therefore "We go out drinking" is a particularly  good idiomatic sentence and is clear in its default meaning.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers the question. The post you quote talks about going *out* eating and going *out* drinking; I'm asking about "to go shopping" and "to go eating", with no "out".

Comment: @TannerSwett - in the example you make I don’t think that  “going shopping”  is different from “going out shopping”.

Comment: Can you explain the quote? And also address 'going eating' and 'go out to eat' ?

Comment: This quote also doesn't seem to provide any explanation at all of *why* "to go out eating" can't be used to mean "to go out to indulge ourselves in the action of eating"; it merely says that that meaning "is not common in the context" without giving any explanation.

Comment: I agree with this quote. There *is* no grammatical reason for one over the other.  (And *we're going eating* is actually okay, even if it's not usual.) It's simply what's ended up being the case.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps one reason the analogy with expressions such as "We're going shopping" fails is what we assume everyone knows about eating. If the response is "We're going shopping", then the question was something like "Why must we go out now?". The asker knows that we're going out but doesn't yet know why.

By contrast, we all know that we will eat at certain times of day. So, if the reason for the trip out is to eat out, then the responder phrases the response as if the asker knows that we will eat but doesn't yet know that the meal will be during the trip out, not at home.